# Android , get user ip address

Tags: android, sockets, ip

I'm using the method below to get the client ip :

```
public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                    boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                    if (useIPv4) {
                        if (isIPv4)
                            return sAddr;
                    } else {
                        if (!isIPv4) {
                            int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 port suffix
                            return delim<0 ? sAddr : sAddr.substring(0, delim);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

In my socket test , my Genymotion emulator has the "192.168.56.101" on it's status bar , I can run a socket and connect to this , it works fine ,

But in the same emulator , when I run this method to get the ip , it will return "10.0.3.15" , as it must return "192.168.56.101".

I don't know where this weird comes from !!! ("10.0.3.15")

How can I get the real user Ip address , I want to connect two people via a socket , so I think I must have their Ip so I can connect them , OR , is it a better way ?

Comment: `10.0.3.15` is a valid IP address. It belongs to the private class A network `10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: so what is "192.168.56.101" , how can I get his Ip ?

Comment: If you want to connect to a peer you need to know its IP address in advance.

Comment: OK , how do I get his ip address , that's all I'm asking :(

Comment: If you would like to connect to my site for example. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

And 10.0.3.15 is localhost address in Geneymotion.